# Criar um ranking móvel baseado numa janela com intervalo de 252 dias

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho uma série temporal do índice de volatilidade implícita (retivol) em dados diários. Amostra de 9 anos. Quero criar um ranking móvel de 20 percentis baseado numa janela móvel de 252 dias anteriores a data *t* e comparar a data *t* com o ranking, caso o valor em *t* seja maior que o valor máximo do ranking de 20 percentis no intervalo de 252 dias anteriores, este dia *t* teria classificação 21 no ranking, e aí rolar esse ranking, diariamente, pelo período de 9 anos.

Criei o seguinte script para tentar fazer vocês entenderem:

```
install.packages("bizdays")
library(bizdays)
dados<- as.data.frame(bizseq('2011-08-01', '2013-08-01', cal = "Brazil/ANBIMA"))
names(dados)<- c("data")

ivol<- as.data.frame(c("21.28711","23.56743","27.32514","28.54277","29.76039","38.40667","47.05294",
                       "27.75004","33.76601","24.37536","28.58706","28.50753","28.42801","28.34848",
                       "28.26896","34.54205","28.226","31.71554","27.61506","26.99005","26.2452",
                       "27.02077","26.57059","25.27205","25.62745","30.41709","30.28928","32.27394","34.2586","36.24326","36.41168",
                       "29.67935","29.76384","28.98926","27.79914","26.60903","32.7296","38.85017","41.72757","42.45641","35.48816",
                       "33.4138","33.17446","38.66989","44.16533","29.40715","38.68258","34.65883","31.78003","28.90124","35.86376",
                       "30.09062","30.2993","26.5146","27.6774","28.84019","30.93672","29.43715","27.37192","26.24751","25.50525",
                       "25.58114","22.27847","24.53868","29.56798","25.89955","25.62683","25.14079","27.00007","28.85935","28.65313",
                       "28.4469","24.9024","29.67527","29.18929","24.76481","35.90339","29.26105","31.60401","30.04701","31.86597",
                       "25.35371","29.55908","24.25097","27.24362","26.0865","27.92838","26.58823","37.58755","25.83994","30.78934",
                       "28.63408","26.47881","25.92757","28.11764","27.20345","25.35408","25.29016","25.76206","24.50687","23.52267",
                       "24.56973","25.61678","26.66384","23.14008","23.132","23.12393","23.17977","23.72229","23.1107","21.90203",
                       "24.00631","20.12761","23.41764","22.58384","23.15579","21.61337","22.57287","22.19599","21.0872","19.83334",
                       "18.18826","19.44424","19.73723","20.03022","18.87538","21.83447","19.94553","19.30423","20.12327","20.31634",
                       "22.5208","18.95442","17.88235","21.26344","21.56118","19.39781","19.76489","20.49098","20.05735","20.25546",
                       "19.42526","17.62972","19.64706","20.71675","19.38761","20.96161","19.54165","21.21596","21.3454","23.25998",
                       "22.7128","21.86852","20.76671","18.82955","18.40445","18.39674","20.23708","20.07432","19.06276","19.61001",
                       "22.36438","19.94096","20.45359","16.62309","18.38752","21.30607","20.14841","19.75784","19.36288","22.72852",
                       "23.30168","19.04908","24.26608","24.14334","23.68773","23.38313","18.41681","24.86972","23.11208","19.85312",
                       "22.99611","22.91279","21.61691","23.89977","21.60447","19.39232","21.9426","21.50965","19.49969","18.71056",
                       "19.46965","19.32327","22.63971","22.113","20.61101","21.01649","27.54151","28.96247","25.58761","26.32041","28.63712",
                       "24.06426","22.23268","34.27249","31.41806","24.22399","32.14149","28.24585","26.57704","23.55219","28.61884","24.66197",
                       "20.94144","27.0632","24.98184","27.34932","26.38455","29.07777","24.41478","25.91706","23.47051","22.43838","23.24079",
                       "22.41391","23.02232","25.72487","26.26527","25.10686","30.60878","26.01148","23.09491","21.65578","21.44434","22.24085",
                       "23.53456","25.41174","27.28891","22.63747","18.35763","24.23522","21.33616","24.65956","23.20137","23.39885","22.76095",
                       "22.12304","23.16902","25.51094","17.30929","27.56798","25.01272","23.84245","26.11669","28.9215","23.04916","23.33632",
                       "21.58664","22.78128","25.99777","22.36353","23.82258","22.38859","22.6706","23.87853","24.92409","23.10635","23.45014",
                       "24.09447","22.24359","24.38719","23.31092","22.23465","25.48968","27.21431","24.76347","25.36156","25.58649","22.7045",
                       "25.42561","22.20385","23.62826","25.47909","25.87671","23.38551","21.71917","22.81986","22.20451","21.6723","20.83679",
                       "22.77583","23.89389","20.59727","22.82012","25.02949","24.43143","24.28433","24.25042","21.27869","20.82378","23.63432",
                       "24.12969","23.81493","24.06198","22.52014","24.60091","20.61036","22.46888","23.03237","23.60265","23.09116","24.44142",
                       "24.17373","22.85317","23.36192","22.47905","23.79545","22.642","21.38135","20.92037","22.56495","21.52126","23.30794",
                       "24.23245","22.79641","25.48476","25.30342","22.87122","23.17207","23.47292","19.94111","21.79934","21.09003","23.71056",
                       "23.20562","22.62287","21.44512","22.12571","22.54461","23.16875","23.07137","23.11263","21.11079","18.45346","22.02743",
                       "22.18733","22.16706","22.14679","21.1788","21.36772","22.0525","20.35522","20.61244","20.86966","21.57509","22.28053",
                       "21.47767","20.67481","18.50791","21.24009","18.85158","20.86887","20.04319","19.76428","20.57738","19.73062","18.80244",
                       "20.47401","18.27169","17.81884","20.38176","20.41285","16.90357","19.77132","20.19383","20.61634","18.8055","18.62108",
                       "16.27306","20.52252","21.5628","21.04483","20.41759","19.91348","19.86341","18.50267","19.28119","19.4508","19.45208",
                       "19.94868","19.80569","20.0529","19.51828","18.75703","19.93031","18.72769","18.18218","19.17099","18.09319","18.63018",
                       "19.54754","18.59208","18.45659","18.67694","18.89729","19.11765","18.89925","19.7338","19.73766","21.42095","19.85507",
                       "20.10499","20.51085","20.58047","19.84328","19.15041","18.33888","18.84041","19.34194","19.84347","20.34499","20.84652",
                       "21.34805","20.45468","21.28042","19.86063","21.49564","23.13064","21.013","22.05263","21.97945","22.73436","21.76791",
                       "21.16098","21.49375","20.58698","21.69745","21.27429","21.2697","22.36205","22.00988","18.99451","20.18173","20.75463",
                       "20.38411","21.68759","20.3392","21.78222","20.39415","19.17879","19.82962","17.29045","20.04898","21.35839","21.70304",
                       "19.20146","20.40494","19.09858","20.58075","22.71482","21.68574","22.76031","23.22045","24.75409","25.10623","23.6726",
                       "26.27497","29.42851","27.17491","27.28767","26.9298","26.85252","28.11517","29.68584","30.51626","30.91683","30.15717",
                       "27.39766","26.24382","24.01179","25.19244","27.26174","26.24734","24.85707","27.99068","25.31346","25.16461","25.01576",
                       "22.98344","23.63146","25.66155","24.72497","25.06169","24.30915","23.4451","22.94747","22.97816","23.49057","22.04397",
                       "22.82086","25.198","23.09666","24.13238","23.86527"))

names(ivol)<- c("retivol")

#fazendo retorno do ivol
ivolnumeric<- as.numeric(ivol$retivol)
ivoln1=c(NA, diff(log(ivolnumeric)))

#criando a base
base<- as.data.frame(dados) 
base$rivoln <-ivoln1

library(dplyr)
#criando a função rank
therank = function(x,y,z, na.rm=FALSE) {
  mutate(x) 
  quantile_rank = ntile(y,z)
}

#tentativa de fazer a janela movel do rank
#função default: rollapplyr(x, 252, fun, na.rm = FALSE) where x is the data 
#(a vector) and fun is a function that calculates the desired value.
library(zoo)

window_rank<- rollapplyr(base, 252, therank, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Teoricamente, o `rollapplyr` deveria fazer o papel da janela móvel, mas, quando rodo o código `window_rank<- rollapplyr(base, 252, therank, na.rm = FALSE)` o R retorna o seguinte erro: `Error in UseMethod("mutate_") :no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: Só `mutate(x)` não faz nada. A variável `x` mudou em quê ou como?

Comment: Rui, o mutate(x) era so a sintaxe da função. A variável que vai ficar no parêntesis do mutate necessariamente precisará ter o nome “x”? Pq no caso, a função therank faz o que eu preciso, mas não dentro do rollapply na forma da janela móvel...

Comment: O `mutate` deverá ter a forma `mutate(base, x = <cálculo>)` com ou sem o nome `x`. A variável `x` se não existir na base é criada com o valor do cálculo e se existir passa a ter esse valor.

Comment: Rui, o script está da seguinte forma: window_rank<- rollapplyr(ivolvec, 252, therank, na.rm = FALSE)`, onde ivolvec é a base, 252 é a janela em dias, therank é a função que criei). 

O `mutate` está dentro da função `therank`, pra eu aplicar a `therank` no `rollapply`é só jogar o nome da função, uma vez que ela está construída no R? Foi o que fiz e volta com esse erro...

Comment: Você precisa postar um exemplo minimamente reproduzível para podermos te dar a solução. Está claro, no entanto, que `mutate(x)` é uma construção equivocada. Você está injetando `x` em `dplyr::mutate()` mas `x` não é um `data.frame`. Por isso que `dplyr::mutate()` não reconhece.

Comment: JdeMello, editei o post inteiro com um código reproduzível! Helpppppppppp!!

Comment: @AparecidaMartins Você poderia disponibilizar um exemplo didático sobre o assunto ou indicar/citar algum material de estudo? Pois penso que para este problema é necessário conhecimento prévio no objeto de estudo. Eu mesmo não conheço nada sobre isto.

Comment: Veja este artigo, bbiasi: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4ur1qy6qid6r9e/Giot_2005_JPM_Relationships%20Between%20Implied%20Volatility%20Indexes%20and%20Stock%20Index%20Returns.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Eu retirei a metodologia desse artigo!